# Unable to parse Xml using C#

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

This is the code:-

```
public void TestXmlDocument()
  {
     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
     XDocument document =  XDocument.Load("XmldataList.xml");

         #region Fetch All the Books 

         var books = from r in document.Descendants("book")
          select new 
              { 
                 Author = r.Element("author").Value,
                 Title = r.Element("title").Value,
                 Genere = r.Element("genre").Value,
                 Price = r.Element("price").Value,
                 PublishDate = r.Element("publish_date").Value,
                 Description = r.Element("description").Value,
              };
            foreach (var r in books)
            {
               Label3.Text=r.PublishDate + r.Title + r.Author;
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            #endregion 

  }
```

I am getting error that

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find
>   file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\XmldataList.xml'.

At line-

```
  XDocument document =  XDocument.Load("XmldataList.xml");
```

Comment: Well does that file exist, and does your program have access to it? Check the path that the error message specifies. Additionally, please put more effort into formatting your code when you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to specify the absolute path to XmldataList.xml:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\XmldataList.xml");
```

Also, it could be helpful to start your IDE with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is using MapPath function as below :

```
String fullPath=MapPath("/XmldataList.xml");
XDocument.Load(fullPath);
```

Otherwise when you push the website on the live server your path might be broken.
If still have problem check out the output of MapPath function, if it is correct, it might be security access issue and you should give IIS the full access to your folder.
Always be careful about file name, sometimes your file name is slightly different with the name in your code.